# How to find a typo in a data frame and replace it

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a data frame with names, surnames, birthdays and some random variables. Lets say it looks like this:

```
    BIRTH  NAME    SURNAME random_value
 1      1  Luke  Skywalker            1
 2      1  Luke  Skywalker            2
 4      2  Leia     Organa            3
 5      3   Han       Solo            7
 7      1   Ben       Solo            1
 8      5 Lando Calrissian            3
 9      3   Han       Solo            4
 10     3   Ham       Solo            4
 11     1  Luke  Wkywalker            9
```

How can I figure out, if there is a typo in name or surname, based on `BIRTH`,`NAME`and `SURNAME`, and then replace the typo with the correct name or surname?

For example, we see, that there are two `Han Solo`s with birthdays on `3`and then there is a `Ham Solo` with the same birthdate. What I would like this algorithm to do is figure out that `Ham`is wrong and replace it with `Han`.

If there are two different spellings which have equal number of occurrences (for same `BIRTH`), it doesn't really matter, which one is chosen, as long that all the `NAME`or `SURNAME`for this group is the same (so always `Ham`or `Han`but not mixed for the same `BIRTH`).

So the end result would be this:

```
BIRTH   NAME          SURNAME random_value
    1      1  Luke  Skywalker            1
    2      1  Luke  Skywalker            2
    4      2  Leia     Organa            3
    5      3   Han       Solo            7
    7      1   Ben       Solo            1
    8      5 Lando Calrissian            3
    11     3   Han       Solo            4
    12     3   Han       Solo            4
    13     1  Luke  Skywalker            9
```

Is there any automated way to do this? My data set is large (>3mill rows) and it would be impossible to check manually.

I would imagine that we look for all the names and surnames with the same birth and then check, if there are some singular outliers that differ only by a letter or that the order of the letters is switched (`Luke`vs `Lkue`). When we find an outlier like that, we replace it.

Comment: If you summarise like so `require(data.table); setDT(df1); df1[, .N, keyby =.(BIRTH, NAME, SURNAME)]` how many records do you end up with, and what's the biggest N value?

Comment: I end up with a little less than 700.000 rows. The biggest N value is 24.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way to find the typos.
First, define the data frame you mention in the question:

```
my_df<-data.frame(BIRTH = c(1,1,2,3,1,5,3,3,1),
       NAME = c("Luke","Luke","Leia","Han","Ben","Lando","Han","Ham","Luke"),
       SURNAME = c("Skywalker","Skywalker","Organa","Solo","Solo","Calrissian","Solo","Solo","Wkywalker"),
       random_value = c(1,2,3,7,1,3,4,4,9))
```

Second, make a new column combining all the entries you want to match on:

```
my_df$birth_and_names <- do.call(paste, c(my_df[c("BIRTH", "NAME", "SURNAME")], sep = " "))
```

Third, define a distance matrix based upon string distance, using the package stringdist:

```
library(stringdist)
dist.matrix<-stringdistmatrix(my_df$birth_and_names,my_df$birth_and_names,method='jw',p=0.1)
row.names(dist.matrix)<-my_df$birth_and_names
names(dist.matrix)<-my_df$birth_and_names
dist.matrix<-as.dist(dist.matrix)
```

Fourth, cluster and display the results as a dendrogram.

```
clusts<-hclust(dist.matrix,method="ward.D2")
plot(clusts)
```

See the dendrogram here:

[image: Dendrogram of related Names]

Now where exactly you want to set your parameters for automatically combining similar results is of course up to you, and depends upon the problem. There are the usual trade-offs between false positives and false negatives.

For this example, cutting at a distance of 0.2 seems appropriate, so:

```
my_df$LikelyGroup<-cutree(clusts,h=0.2)
```

where now `my_df$LikelyGroup` is the column of identifiers which has one number per individual, even if they are miss-spelled.

Now to name the groups, find the mode for each name/birthday column:

```
library(dplyr)

Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

my_df<-my_df%>%
  group_by(LikelyGroup)%>%
  mutate(Group_Birth=Mode(BIRTH),
         Group_Name=Mode(NAME),
         Group_Surname=Mode(SURNAME))
```

Output my_df:

```
 BIRTH|NAME |SURNAME   | random_value| LikelyGroup| Group_Birth|Group_Name |Group_Surname 
------|-----|----------|-------------|------------|------------|-----------|--------------
     1|Luke |Skywalker |            1|           1|           1|Luke       |Skywalker     
     1|Luke |Skywalker |            2|           1|           1|Luke       |Skywalker     
     2|Leia |Organa    |            3|           2|           2|Leia       |Organa        
     3|Han  |Solo      |            7|           3|           3|Han        |Solo          
     1|Ben  |Solo      |            1|           4|           1|Ben        |Solo          
     5|Lando|Calrissian|            3|           5|           5|Lando      |Calrissian    
     3|Han  |Solo      |            4|           3|           3|Han        |Solo          
     3|Ham  |Solo      |            4|           3|           3|Han        |Solo          
     1|Luke |Wkywalker |            9|           1|           1|Luke       |Skywalker
```

See gist at https://gist.github.com/gdmcdonald/9135ec8f7e903a0735a0b16d8cb97297

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest any way to slice the data so that this method is doable in a reasonable time? If I try to create a matrix that is 3mil x 3mil large, r stops responding.
Also, any advice how to, now that I have the group numbers, change the names with typos.

Comment: I have solved the slicing issue (will use `group_by(BIRTH)`. This assumes that birthdays are correct, but I can live with that. So I would just ask for your help with assigning right names to groups, if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Hi @Ravonrip, I have edited my answer to add the names.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but do you have any advice on slicing the data so that it executes in reasonable time? I tried and thought it would be enough but it wasn't when I tested it.

Comment: Probably with large data a knn clustering algorithm would work better than hierarchical.