# How to find and correct typos in a data frame in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with names, surnames, birthdays and some random variables. Lets say it looks like this:

```
    BIRTH  NAME    SURNAME random_value institution
 1      1  Luke  Skywalker            1        1111
 2      1  Luke  Skywalker            2        1111
 4      2  Leia     Organa            3        1211
 5      3   Han       Solo            7        1342
 7      1   Ben       Solo            1        1342
 8      5 Lando Calrissian            3        1111
 9      3   Han       Solo            4        1111
 10     3   Ham       Solo            4        1342
 11     1  Luke  Wkywalker            9        1111
```

How can I figure out, if there is a typo in name or surname, based on `BIRTH`,`NAME`and `SURNAME`, and then replace the typo with the correct name or surname?

For example, we see, that there are two `Han Solo`s with birthdays on `3`and then there is a `Ham Solo` with the same birthdate. What I would like this algorithm to do is figure out that `Ham`is wrong and replace it with `Han`.

If there are two different spellings which have equal number of occurrences (for same `BIRTH`), it doesn't really matter, which one is chosen, as long that all the `NAME`or `SURNAME`for this group is the same (so always `Ham`or `Han`but not mixed for the same `BIRTH`).

So the end result would be this:

```
    BIRTH  NAME    SURNAME random_value institution
 1      1  Luke  Skywalker            1        1111
 2      1  Luke  Skywalker            2        1111
 4      2  Leia     Organa            3        1211
 5      3   Han       Solo            7        1342
 7      1   Ben       Solo            1        1342
 8      5 Lando Calrissian            3        1111
 9      3   Han       Solo            4        1111
 10     3   Han       Solo            4        1342
 11     1  Luke  Skywalker            9        1111
```

Is there any automated way to do this? My data set is large (>3mill rows) and it would be impossible to check manually.

I would imagine that we look for all the names and surnames with the same birth and then check, if there are some singular outliers that differ only by a letter or that the order of the letters is switched (`Luke`vs `Lkue`). When we find an outlier like that, we replace it.

I already asked this in `R`forums ([How to find a typo in a data frame and replace it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990947/how-to-find-a-typo-in-a-data-frame-and-replace-it)) and got a reply. I tried to implement that method directly (it failed miserably, because of time complexity). I then modified it and used it on smaller sub data frames (grouped by `BIRTH`). But even then, I stoped the process when `R` estimated it will take more than 37 hours and that number was climbing.

Is there any faster way to do this in `python`. I would be really grateful if you could give me any suggestion.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, there is a possibility, that two persons with a similar name (Jon/John Smit(h)) will be born on the same date. In this case, we would either look at the institution column (each person should (but the reality of the data set can be a bit different) appear 8-9 times with one institution number and 3-4 times with another one). Also, more than one person share the same institution number.

But because of possible faulty data with `institution`, we can also use the following reasoning:
If the identical full name for the same birthday appears more than twice, we can conclude that it is in fact a new person, not a typo (as two (out of max 13) identical typos for the same person are unlikely), and leave it's name like it is.

Comment: How would you handle similar, but legitimately different, names with the same birthday?  E.g. (B/C)laire (J/D)anes?  Jo(h)n Smit(h/t)?

Comment: Maybe I gave a bad example table. There is another column, that has a 4 digit code. Every person should have (in ideal conditions) 8 or 9 rows and 4 different rows with the same code (it is actually their institution code). Maybe that is something that should be taken in account. Or simpler, if there is, a "name surname" permutation, that occurred more that twice or trice, we can assume that it is not a typo but a different person (as the event of a same typo happening twice or trice for the same person is unlikely and it has to mean a new person.)

Comment: In that case, consider updating your example to be more representative of your data - it'll be easier to help you that way.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

first of all i group the birth with the names, and list the resulting surnames. So i would get

```
['Fkywalker', 'Skywalker', 'Skywalker']
```

After that I find out the name with the most occurences (Skywalker) and compare the other names with this one. To find typos, I calculate the [Levenshtein-distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). 
When the distance is below 3, I assume it's a typo and update a dict like that:

```
{'wrong_name' : 'right_name'}
```

Then I make the same procedure with the names.

Then you have two replacement dicts and you can simply replace the wrong values.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import distance
    from collections import Counter 

    dict_SURNAME = dict()
    dict_NAME = dict()

    def dist(str1, str2):
        return distance.levenshtein(str1, str2)

    def find_name(namelist, todict):
        for names in namelist:
            namesorted = Counter(names).most_common()
            for name in namesorted[1:]:
                if dist(namesorted[0][0], name[0]) < 3:
                    todict.update({name[0]: namesorted[0][0]})

    dfsurname = df1.groupby(['BIRTH', 'NAME']).SURNAME.apply(list).reset_index()
    find_name(dfsurname.SURNAME.tolist(), dict_SURNAME)

    dfname = df1.groupby(['BIRTH', 'SURNAME']).NAME.apply(list).reset_index()
    find_name(dfname.NAME.tolist(), dict_NAME)

    print(dict_SURNAME)
    print(dict_NAME)

    df2 = df1.replace({'NAME': dict_NAME, 'SURNAME': dict_SURNAME})
    print(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The library [pandas-dedupe](https://github.com/Lyonk71/pandas-dedupe) can do exactly what you want.
It gives you the chance to find duplicate rows containing some typos and canonicalize them.

```
pip install pandas-dedupe
```

And here is a short code example

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_dedupe

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'city':
    ['Seattle', 'Saettle', 'Seatle', 'Seattle',
    'New york', '  New York', 'NewYork',
    'London', 'london', 'L ondon',
    'Milan', 'Milan', 'Milan', 'Milano',
    'Paris', 'paris', 'Paris', 'Paris'],
    
    'country' : 
    ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA',
    'USA', 'USA', 'USA',
    'UK', 'UK', 'UK', 
    'ITA', 'ITA', 'ITA', 'ITA',
    'FRA', 'FRA', 'FRA', 'FRA']
    })

# Deduplication and canonicalization
dd_df = pandas_dedupe.dedupe_dataframe(
    df,                         # Dataframe to deduplicate
    field_properties=['city', 'country'], # List of fields to base deduplication on
    canonicalize=['city'],      # List of fields to canonicalize (optional)
    sample_size=0.8,            # Size of sample of records to be labelled
)
```

In this example, you deduplicate rows based on their value in the `city` and `country` columns and canonicalize the values for the variable `city`.

And here is a short explanation of how it works:
`pandas-dedupe` will ask you to label a sample of records as distinct or duplicates. After labelling, dedupe will figure out the probabilities that two or more records are duplicates and deduplicate and canonicalize for you.

Note: the canonical name chosen by dedupe is the most frequent name in each cluster.